# Delete files and folders in a specified folder

Tags: batch-file

I want to delete all files and folders in a specified folder. The end result should be that the folder is not deleted itself, just empty. In the linux world it is:

```
rm -rf /home/kasper/*
```

I have tried `del`, `deltree` and `rd` without luck. They either just delete files or delete everything including the folder itself.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Answer (score 2):

this script inside your folder should solve it:

```
    for /D %%F in (*) do  ( rmdir /s/q .\%%~F)
    del /q *.*
```

Comment: I wonder why you do not just add `cd /D folder` to the beginning of the script or prepend the wildcards with `folder\ ` instead of noticing that it should be executed inside the folder. Otherwise it's good!

Answer (score 1):

```
rmdir /s/q  folder
```

Comment: This deletes everything, including the `folder` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running Windows.

The basic command line tools in Windows are rather limited. However, you can do this and many other tasks easily in [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powershell):

```
remove-item C:\test\* -recurse
```

If you prefer the Linux way, you can use [UnxUtils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/), which is a collection of Unix command line tools natively compiled for Windows. I always have these in my `PATH`.